# Can this Java code be made more efficient

Tags: java

I have Java code that applies a function to every element of a HashSet. Each element has to be (1) removed from the HashSet,(2)processed, which returns a result of the same type (and sometimes even the same object instance), and sometimes multiple instances of this type in a collection; (3)the result is replaced in a HashSet.

I delete each element from the original HashSet, processing it's elements until its empty.  I place each new instance returned by processing the object in a new HashSet. When I’m done I discard the old HashSet and continue with the new one. I thought I had to do this because otherwise, I risk an infinite loop as I iterate over every element of HashSet while also adding elements to it. 
The code kinda looks like this. Fct addToHashSet adds 1 or more elements to newSet.

```
        newSet= new HashSet< myObjectType >(); 
        for (myObjectType s : origSet){
            addToHashSet(newSet, process(s,message)); 
        }
        return newSet;
```

My questions are:

1)  Am I being inefficient by constantly creating and deleting HashSets (this processing is called a lot)?

2)  If so, is there a better, in place, manner to process every element once, (I don,t want to process elements that I just added) without creating a new HashSet?

3)  If the answer is no, can it be dome for cases where each element of the Hashset is replaced with *a single* instance? That code looks like that:

```
        newSet= new HashSet< myObjectType >(); 
        for (myObjectType s : origSet){
            newSet .add(process(s,message)); 
        }
        return newSet;
```

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: From what it sounds like, you need a hashset or a hashtable that can accept collisions (multiple of the same entries).

Comment: If you have some sense of the data, you may want to set the initial capacity ahead of time

Comment: It is off topic, but you can also stop using the `foreach` style for loop since you are effectively creating an iterator for each iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How should I have written it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need the properties of a `Set`,
and if your process returns new instances,
as opposed to modifying the instances in the set,
then your current solution is fine.

If the process modifies the instances instead of returning new instances,
then you can use the `forEach` method instead:

```
origSet.forEach(item -> process(item));
```

If you don't need the properties of a `Set`, then you could use a `Queue<>` instead:

```
int size = queue.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    queue.add(process(queue.poll()));
}
```

At the end of this loop, the original elements of the `queue` will be all gone, it will contain the new elements returned by `process`.

And if you really need a new set replacing the old one,
then you can use a more idiomatic solution with streams (as [@Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310566/simon-forsberg) pointed out in a comment):

```
newSet = origSet.stream().map(s -> process(s, message)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thanks that seems like a good solution. About the properties of the    Set , I just need it to be unordered. I check for doubles manually before adding them. So it seems to me that queue actually has structly more structure and properties than the     Set .